# How to document that a constructor function generates objects which have what properties (and also methods)?

Tags: javascript, jsdoc

I have a constructor function, and Im using JSDoc to document it:

```js
/**
 * @constructor
 * @param {String} title The title of the task
 * @param {Boolean} important Whether the task is important of not
 */
function Task(title, important) {
    this.title = title
    this.important = important

    // 1 presents to 'unfinished', 2 presents to 'processing', 3 presents to 'finished'
    this.state = 1
}
```

The documentation is generated:

[image]

But here is a thing. You see in my constructor function, it is has a property with the name of `state`, and there is no paramater use to set the value of the `state` property.

And so when I document this `Task` constructor function, I have no idea how to tell the readers this function generates objects which have a `state` property. And by the way, I think the developers when they read the documentation, they will know the objects generated by this `Task` function has the `title` and `important` properties is because those properties documented under parameters. And since the `state` property it doesn't "rely" on any parameter, I don't know how to show it on the documentation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add a `@typedef` type definition for your `Task` objects:

```js
/**
 * @typedef {object} Task
 * @property {string} title The title of the task
 * @property {boolean} important Whether the task is important of not
 * @property {number} state 1 represents 'unfinished', 2 represents 'processing', 3 represents 'finished'
 */
```

and add a `@returns` to your constructor function documentation:

```js
/**
 * @constructor
 * @param {String} title The title of the task
 * @param {Boolean} important Whether the task is important of not
 * @returns {Task} a task object
 */
function Task(title, important) {
    this.title = title
    this.important = important

    // 1 presents to 'unfinished', 2 presents to 'processing', 3 presents to 'finished'
    this.state = 1
}
```